# Problem with jdb debugger

Tags: debugging

I am trying to use Ubuntu 12.04 lts on a system76 box.

when I try to run the java debugger, jdb, i get a timeout after i attempt to run the application. i have tried several things and I think the problem has to do with the `/etc/hosts` file.

my call to jdb is very simple:

`jdb main.RunSim`    where my main class resides

i have also tried calls that attempt to attach to an existing VM
and get the same results

the `/etc/hosts` file is:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.1.1 my machine name
```

## a bunch of lines for ipv6 capable hosts including

```
::1 ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
```

any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Well, it could be anything, try running the whole session under strace, log it to a file to see where it might be hanging.